# Map array from one type into antoher using typescript interfaces

Tags: typescript

I try to map an array from one interface type into another, my code looks like this:

```
interface Entry { ... }

 return this.dataService.getData(id).pipe(
      map(data => ({
        ...data,
        array: data.array.map(entry => {
          if (
            instanceOfEntryB(entry) ||
            entry.options === undefined
          ) {
            return entry;
          } else {
            return <Entry & { options: SelectItem[] }>{
              ...entry,
              options: entry.options.map<SelectItem>(
                option => ({
                  description: option.label,
                  value: option.key,
                  selected: false
                })
              )
            };
          }
        })
      })),
      tap(({ array }) => {
        ctx.patchState({ array });
      })
    );
```

`data.array` is typed as `Entry & { options?: Option[] }` and `array` within the state as `Entry & { options?: SelectItem[] }`. Wihtin the `ctx.patchState` for `array`, the linter throws an error: *Type 'Option' is missing the following properties from type 'SelectItem': value, selected, description*`

How can I solve this problem the smartest way?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/yNa7PW) so that others can demonstrate your issue for themselves?  Ideally example code should be both sufficient ("reproducible") and necessary ("minimal") to convey the nature of the problem to others.  You'll have a greater chance of getting an answer that actually helps you.  Good luck!

Comment: Don't pass explicit type arguments to generic functions such as `Array.prototype.map`.